# Append an object to a list with django GenericViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-generic-views

I wrote a many-to-many field for my model but when I try to write an updated view with generic-view-set don't append the new obj just replace it,how can I write to append the new obj to list, my model:

```
    class Portfolio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=True, default='portfolio')
    user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='investor')
    assets = models.ManyToManyField(Assets, related_name='portfolio_assets')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Serializer

```
    class PortfolioUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Portfolio
        fields = ['id', 'name']
```

View

```
    class PortfolioAssetsUpdate(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet
                            ):
    queryset = Portfolio.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PortfolioAssetsUpdateSerializer

    def put(self, request, pk):
        return self.update(request, pk)
```

Now my problem is when I update my portfolio, a new object replaces to old one, I need to append new to old,I really don't have any idea

Comment: Are you trying to establish  many-to-many relationship between  existing portfolio_object and new assets that you recieved in put request?

Comment: yes, Am trying to append a new obj(asset) to the portfolio, if the user wanted to edit it and add new assets to old assets.

Comment: If you want to add new Asset object to the existing Portfolio object, then you need to create Asset object and add it to the existing portfolio_object. Then you can get all the assets object that are in relationship with portfolio_object.

Comment: I did it too,but it doesn't work that's why I asked here, to see the code example